# The action '74' could not be found for MenusController

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In `menuList.html.erb`:

`<%= link_to("Edit",{:action=>'edit',:id=>menu.id})%>`

In `menus_controller`:

```
def edit
    @menu=Menu.find(params[:id])    
end

def update
   @menu=Menu.find(params[:id])
   if @menu.update_attributes(menu_params)     
       flash[:notice]="Menu Updated Successfully"    
   else
       endrender('edit')
end
end
def menu_params
    params.require(:menu).permit(:menu_item_name,:price,:item_type,:image)
end
```

in `menus/edit`:
`<%= form_for(:menu,:url=>{:action=>'update',:id=>@menu.id}) do |f|%>.....`

Problem I am facing :

1. When I am clicking `Edit` and visited the edit page I am getting a wrong URL '../menus/74/edit', I think it should be '../menus/edit/74'.
2. After clicking `Save Edit` I am getting `The action '74' could not be found for MenusController`.Please help me I am new in rails.

Answer (score 0):

In you config/routes.rb add something like:

```
resources :menu do
 member do
   get 'edit' # or post or any other method as per your need
 end
end
```

For reference on editing routes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: `root 'categories#login'`

 ` resources :orders`

  `resources :line_items`

 ` resources :carts`
 ` resources :menus`
 ` resources :menu do`
 `member do`
   get 'edit`'
 `end`
`end`
 
  get 'hotels/index'

  get 'hotels/show'


 `match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:option)',:via=>[:get,:post]`  I have used that code but it's not working.